# how to implement trigger concept in hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, triggers

I’m brand new to big data echo system but I have good SQL knowledge and I have worked only in relational databases. There is a scenario in my case.  We have a table in Hive which records error details from the log. My requirement is whenever data is inserted into the error log table system, it should trigger an alert mail. I’m looking for a kind of “database trigger” . I know a trigger is not possible in a Hive table since it is a warehouse table. My question is: Is there any workaround to achieve this?

Comment: how are you inserting data to your table ?

Answer (score 0):

I propose that you use rather elasticsearch for your need, with watcher or xpack you generate alerts. Hive here is not the good technoligy for your needs